# How to add/remove echo/noise for a given wave file

Tags: echo, addition, wav, noise

Without knowing about noise and echo, I am asking this question. How to remove/add noise /echo for a given WAV file? Please provide suggestions/guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to "remove" noise from a signal, you must have or recreate the noise you want to remove and substract that from your audio. So it depends on whether you can isolate or replicate the problem signal.

To a certain extent "noise" (hiss or other constant sound) can be cleaned from an audio signal and there are various applications/plugins that attempt to do this - success depends on the consistency and amplitude of the noise vs signal.

Removing "echo" (not sure what you mean by this, but I assume you mean "reverb", or acoustic properties of the space the sound was recorded in) is extremely complex since it is not consistent and in most cases would be impossible to replicate.

Comment: Thanks for u r comment .. can i have any links on this ..?

Answer (score 0):

Removing noise I believe, removing the background noise, also be known as ambient noise.
Usually there are two step to remove noise from audio.

1. Create a background noise_profile
2. Audio - noise_profile = Clean Audio

There are two ways we can do the above.

**Audacity:**
Steps

- install audacity desktop app
  [image]
- open and go to the file menu and select the audio for noise removal
  [image]
  if you listen to the file, you can realize the silence clear noise and the frequency of that portion is small. That need to be removed from the call.
  [image]
- Select the noise portion from the audio
  [image]
- Go to effect menu >> then select noise reduction >> click on Get Noise Profile
  [image]
- Then ctrl + a to select the complete audio to apply noise profile to reduce noise
- from effect menu >> noise reduction >> click on ok to apply noise profile into the audio. You can adjust the parameter and test which one is best. If you set this high you may lose few words. 
  [image]
  Now you can see the noise from the silence portion has gone. You can validate by listening to those. 
  [image]

**SOX:** Steps

- Install SOX
- Create background noise profile using the audio file

  /usr/bin/sox noise.wav -n noiseprof noise.prof
- Remove noise from mp3 using profile

  /usr/bin/sox noise.wav clean.wav noisered noise.prof 0.20